# IOS Different UI Elements In UIViewController After Network Call

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, afnetworking

I have a View Controller for users' profiles.

Users can be of 2 different types A and B, which are known once the Network Call (using AFNetworking) is completed.

I am having a hard time how to organize the Profile View Controller Life Cycle to fit that need:

```
- loadView method adds a ScrollView which is common for both userA and userB categories.
```

Then in the network callback, one of these 2 methdos are called

```
- configureCategoryA 
- configureCategoryB
```

whose job is to had UI elements correspondent to A or B.
UI is not very smooth.

Any idea how to improve such a process for the User Experience?

Answer (score 0):

This is a UX question.

The simplest answer is that this should / cannot be the first VC that the user sees.  If it is, then you can hide it with a welcome screen "Let's get started...", while connecting to the server in the background, for the first time.  After that, you could presumably store the user type so subsequent loads are immediate.

If it is not the first VC that the user sees, then again do this call upon first load, so that you can immediately present the correct view, even if you still have to page in live data from the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand what you, and in fact that work for the current user's own profile, but the situation I described applies when the current User taps another user picture for instance and then the tapped user profile view controller appears. Am I clear enough?

Comment: If you are say selecting from a list and you already have a photo, then you have already downloaded at least some basic data.  When you do that, you can also cache the user type.  That way, even if you need to do an asynchronous call to get further details, you at least know what the view will be, and can page in the data as you get it.  If it were my code, I would eagerly grab all basic user data contacts visible to the app-user, you and query the server "just in time" for other users as the list is scrolled.